# Java result 1 error

Tags: java, file, io, midi, javax.sound.midi

I wanted to create a midi file which consist of these notes. I took this code from internet. If i can find out the problem to this i can go further. When i run this application i only get an error call "java result 1" error. What i need is after i run this there there should be a midi file generated which consist of the notes which i have passed. The complete code is available.

```
public class CreateSequence{
  private static final int VELOCITY = 64;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        printUsageAndExit();
    }
    File outputFile = new File(args[0]);
    Sequence    sequence = null;
    try {
        sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 1);
    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }   
    Track track = sequence.createTrack();

    // first chord: C major
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(60, 0));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(64, 0));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(67, 0));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(72, 0));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(60, 1));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(64, 1));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(67, 1));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(72, 1));

    // second chord: f minor N
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(53, 1));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(65, 1));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(68, 1));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(73, 1));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(63, 2));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(65, 2));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(68, 2));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(73, 2));

    // third chord: C major 6-4
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(55, 2));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(64, 2));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(67, 2));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(72, 2));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(64, 3));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(72, 3));

    // forth chord: G major 7
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(65, 3));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(71, 3));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(55, 4));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(65, 4));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(67, 4));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(71, 4));

    // fifth chord: C major
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(48, 4));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(64, 4));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(67, 4));
    track.add(createNoteOnEvent(72, 4));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(48, 8));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(64, 8));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(67, 8));
    track.add(createNoteOffEvent(72, 8));

    //Now we just save the Sequence to the file we specified.
    //The '0' (second parameter) means saving as SMF type 0.
    //Since we have only one Track, this is actually the only option
    //(type 1 is for multiple tracks).
    try {
        MidiSystem.write(sequence, 0, outputFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  private static MidiEvent createNoteOnEvent(int nKey, long lTick) {
    return createNoteEvent(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, nKey, VELOCITY, lTick);
  }

  private static MidiEvent createNoteOffEvent(int nKey, long lTick) {
    return createNoteEvent(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, nKey, 0, lTick);
  }

  private static MidiEvent createNoteEvent(int nCommand, int nKey,
                                           int nVelocity, long lTick) {
    ShortMessage message = new ShortMessage();
    try {
        message.setMessage(nCommand, 0, nKey, nVelocity); // 0 always on channel 1
    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    MidiEvent event = new MidiEvent(message, lTick);
    return event;
  }

  private static void printUsageAndExit(){
        out("usage:");
        out("java CreateSequence <midifile>");
        System.exit(1);
  }

  private static void out(String strMessage) {
    System.out.println(strMessage);
  }
}
```

This is the output

```
   usage:
   java CreateSequence <midifile>
   Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Paste the exact output that you get when you run it.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Java result 1" error. The only thing this can mean in your context is that the application is terminating with a status code of 1, which means it's hitting one of the `System.exit(1)` lines of your code. But without further information, it's impossible to say why that would be happening.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it want hit any `System.exit(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the output file name as an arg. It's exiting with Code 1 because it calls printUsafeAndExit() if you don't run it with the correct arg count. Try running it as:

```
java CreateSequence output.mid
```

If you have trouble passing args (can be confusing for beginners if you're using an IDE like Eclipse), just dele this check:

```
if (args.length != 1) {
    printUsageAndExit();
}
```

And hardcode the output file:

```
File outputFile = new File("output.mid");
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking this Java program? The code expects one argument to be passed at the command line. Looking at the output it looks like the method

```
private static void printUsageAndExit()
{
    out("usage:");
    out("java CreateSequence <midifile>");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

is getting invoked. You need to pass (i believe) the file name to the program when you run it